# Windows Authentication from Linux client to Windows SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux, authentication

I have a business requirement. I have an agent running on Linux Box connecting to SQL server using SQL authentication.

But I want to use Windows authentication instead of SQL authentication. The recent JDBC driver supports it and I want to do authentication using NTLM.

Let me know if more details required.

Thanks….

Comment: can you specify what linux distro are you using. how are you trying to connect?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu. I had tried using kerberose authenitcation following the given link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558122.aspx But I am not sure how to do it using NTLM.

Comment: from NTLM do you mean NTLM proxy